# Expressions to refer to some point in the future

Tags: phrase-request, expressions, idiomatic-language, future-time

Which of the following expressions is idiomatic and\or grammatical?

> - I think I will be busy until I become 45 or something. **By that
>     time**, my children will be mature enough to depend more on themselves.
> - I think I will be busy until I become 45 or something. **When *the \
>     this* time comes**, my children will be mature enough to depend more on
>     themselves.
> - I think I will be busy until I become 45 or something. **At that
>     time**, my children will be mature enough to depend more on themselves.

Comment: All your examples are fine, and none of them really have any subtle "nuance" differentiating them from alternatives. But I'd be prepared to bet that in practice, ***By then*** (which you *didn't* include) would be by far the most common form.

Comment: (Note that idiomatically, it's *...until I **am** 45*, not ***become***. More naturally, *...until **I'm** 45*.)